# If $(X, Y)$ are jointly independent of $Z$, is $Var(X|Y, Z) = Var(X|Y)$?

Tags: probability, variance

If $(X, Y)$ are jointly independent of $Z$, then $P(X|Y, Z) = \frac{P(X, Y)P(Z)}{P(Y)P(Z)} = P(X|Y)$.

In this case, is $Var(X|Y, Z) = Var(X|Y)$?

Comment: Yes - the probability distribution is independent of Z thus all moments are independent of Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any statistics of $X,Y$ given $Z$ can be written with only $X$ and $Y$. That's what joint independence of $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ implies.